# Async-await not working as anticipated. Value is 'undefined' after using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm using socket.io with node js. For the authentication, I'm using middleware in socket.io but the code is not waiting for the middleware to finish its work thus the value is 'undefined'.

**Here is the main function.**

```
module.exports = async (server) => {

  const io = require('socket.io')(server);

  io.on(CONNECTION, async function (socket) {

      var email = await authenticateUser(io);
       console.log(email); // 'undefined'
      user = new User(email);
  });
}
```

**Middleware function**

```
async function authenticateUser(io) {

    io.use(async (socket, next) => {

        const handshakeData = socket.handshake.query;
        const token = handshakeData.token;

        const Email = await Token.isValid(token);

        console.log("Auth ---> " + Email); // here it is fine

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            if (Email) {
                res(Email);
            } else {
                rej();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Authtentication function**

```
exports.isValid = async (token) => {

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_KEY);
        console.log(decoded.email) // here it is fine
        return decoded.email;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Thank you!***

Comment: `return Email;`, no need to return a promise in that arrow function as it is already marked as async/await and you are already awaiting a result.

Comment: Avoid passing `async function`s as callbacks. Your `io.use` callback isn't promisified at all, and `authenticateUser` doesn't wait for anything. Also, `isValid` should not be `async`.

Comment: @Bergi  yeah, I was trying a lot of things so forgot to remove the async from`isValid`. But thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise you are creating inside `authenticateUser` is not visible to the caller since it is created inside the scope of the function you are passing to `io.use()`.

Instead, try creating the promise one lexical level higher so that it is visible after you are finished with the socket.io event handler:

```
// middleware function
function authenticateUser(io) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    io.use(async (socket, next) => {

        const handshakeData = socket.handshake.query;
        const token = handshakeData.token;

        const Email = await Token.isValid(token);
            if (Email) {
                resolve(Email);
            } else {
                reject(); // should probably put an error here
            }
        });
    });
}
```